# AngularJS is not showing JSON data in list view

Tags: angularjs, json

I've spent few hours on this and I just can't get the data to display on the page. I'm not getting any errors & I'm able to see the retrieved data in console tool box. Here is my code-

In the html page -

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="menuContent in profileMenu">
                <a href="profileMenu/{{menuContent.menuId}}">
                    {{menuContent.menuItem}}
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside the .json file -

```
[{
    "menuId":"1",
    "menuItem":"About"
},{
    "menuId":"2",   
    "menuItem":"Timeline"
},{
    "menuId":"3",
    "menuItem":"Teams"
},{
    "menuId":"4",   
    "menuItem":"Liked Profiles"
}]
```

Inside the JS file -

```
$http({
    method: "get",
    url: "data/custom-menu.json"
}).then(function(profileMenuContent){
    $scope.profileMenu = profileMenuContent;
    console.log($scope.profileMenu.data);
});
```

Comment: Can you do a plunker? Also do you have ng-app and ng-controller in your html?

Comment: Inside JSON you had object name as "menuId" and "menuItem". But in HTML you are using like "id" and "name". Please change and check

Comment: Yes Srijith! I added ng-app & ng-controller in html file. Remaining code is working fine. But the problem is with the list only.

Comment: Yes Thangadurai! I edited the code as your suggestion. But still the list was not displaying. Can you help me more?

Comment: check the below answer@rroxysam

Comment: Thank you for your answer @rroxysam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you mates for your suggestions! I'm able to view the json data now. The bug is in .js file. As I'm using promise to call the data, I should use '.data' to get data into $scope variable. Here is the final code -

In HTML file :

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-8">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="menuContent in profileMenu">
            <a href="profileMenu/{{menuContent.menuId}}">
                {{menuContent.menuItem}}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In Json :

```
[{
"menuId":"1",
"menuItem":"About"
 },{
"menuId":"2",   
"menuItem":"Timeline"
 },{
"menuId":"3",
"menuItem":"Teams"
 },{
"menuId":"4",   
"menuItem":"Liked Profiles"
 }]
```

In js file-

```
$http({
method: "get",
url: "data/custom-menu.json"
}).then(function(profileMenuContent){
$scope.profileMenu = profileMenuContent.data;
console.log($scope.profileMenu.data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is working code-

```js
'use strict';
 var app = angular.module("demo", [], function($httpProvider) {

});

app.controller("demoCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.profileMenu = [{
    "menuId":"1",
    "menuItem":"About"
},{
    "menuId":"2",   
    "menuItem":"Timeline"
},{
    "menuId":"3",
    "menuItem":"Teams"
},{
    "menuId":"4",   
    "menuItem":"Liked Profiles"
}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="demoCtrl">
           <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="menuContent in profileMenu">
                    <a href="profileMenu/{{menuContent.menuId}}">
                        {{menuContent.menuItem}}
                    </a>
              </li>
          </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, I edited the code according to your answer. But still the list is not displaying.

Comment: @NagaHemanth i have updated a working example. (it does not get the data from http request  but you could set the variable in http request as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Right now, You've wrong `key` in HTML

Use `menuContent.menuId` instead of `menuContent.id` and use `menuContent.menuItem` instead of `menuContent.name`.

This will work!

Comment: I edited the code as per your instruction. But the problem still persists & not displaying the list.

Comment: I'm getting the whole data of json file like this-
{   "menuId":"1",
    "menuItem":"About"},{ "menuId":"2",   
    "menuItem":"Timeline"},{ "menuId":"3",
    "menuItem":"Teams"},{ "menuId":"4",   
    "menuItem":"Liked Profiles"}

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Code :

```
$http({
       method: "get",
       url: "data/custom-menu.json"
}).then(function(profileMenuContent){
      $scope.profileMenu = profileMenuContent.data;
      console.log($scope.profileMenu);
});
```

You are using promise in your service, so it will returned your data in profileMenuContent.data.

Comment: Thank you rroxysam! Its working. After adding ".data", it is working fine. What's the secret behind this?

Comment: The reason is that .then() returns the object which also contains other information about the $http request & the actual request data holds in data property.So we have to use .data property to get our actual data. You can also verify it by consoling the response from then/promise, which will return a object.

Comment: @Naga signs of emerging stackoverflow developer(copy, Paste & earn)